# Combine tmap and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tmap, cowplot

I am trying to combine *test1*, a map made with tmap,  with *test2*, a plot made with ggplot2, using cowplot::plot_grid.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tmap)
library(cowplot)
library(ggplotify)

test2 <-ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + geom_point()

data("World")

test1 <- tm_shape(World) + tm_polygons("HPI")

plot_grid(test1,test2)
```

tmap doesn't seem to be compatible with cowplot:

"In as_grob.default(plot) :
Cannot convert object of class tmap into a grob"

same problem when using

```
tmap::tmap_arrange(test1,test2)
```

"Error in tmap_arrange(test1, test2) :
Not all arguments are tmap objects "

I also tried to convert the tmap using functions like "as.grob" from ggplotify,

```
test3 <- as.grob(test1)
```

but no luck
"Error in UseMethod("as.grob") :
no applicable method for 'as.grob' applied to an object of class "tmap" "

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I've recently added `tmap_grob` which does the job.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tmap)
library(cowplot)
library(ggplotify)

test2 <-ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color = Species)) + geom_point()

data("World")

tm <- tm_shape(World) + tm_polygons("HPI")
test1 <- tmap_grob(tm)

plot_grid(test1,test2)
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn, I couldn't have hoped for a better answer :)